# JS .length method not working inside an loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the `.length` of a string inside a *NodeList* by using a `.forEach` loop. But it is not recognized as a property.

```
const headings = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3");
console.log(headings.length)

headings.forEach(heading => {
    let headingLenth = heading.length;
    console.log(headingLenth);
})
```

I tried using a `for of` loop and it happens the same. It only works if I use the `.length` property in the 'outside', as I printed my global var (second line of the code).

**Output:**

[image: this image].

Comment: Do not post code in images. Edit your question to post the code itself.

Comment: `heading` is a Node, not list. So `.length` does not exist on it. If you expect same value, it should be `headings.length`

Comment: I am no front-end dev, but I can tell you that your outside log is logging the length of the resulting array.  Meaning you have 3 headings in the headings collection.  When you do the `forEach` each individual element is probably an HTML object.  To get to its contents you probably have to do `heading.innerText.length`, or `heading.innerHTML.length` or something around those lines.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [Jose Ramirez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13886104/jos%c3%a9-ram%c3%adrez), you need to access the text node of each header element with `heading.innerText`. Then you can get the length of the content string.

```js
const headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3')
console.log(headings.length)

headings.forEach(heading => {
  let headingLength = heading.innerText.length
  console.log(headingLength)
})
```

```html
<h1>Longest Heading</h1>
<h2>Short Heading</h2>
<h3>Min Heading</h3>
```